# Append to file failure when executable not in same folder as data files

Tags: c#, file-io

Problem is now solved. Mistake by me that I hadn't seen before.

I am pretty new to coding in general and am very new to C# so I am probably missing something simple. I wrote a program to pull data from a login website and save that data to files on the local hard drive. The data is power and energy data for solar modules and each module has its own file. On my main workstation I am running Windows Vista and the program works just fine. When I run the program on the machine running Server 2003, instead of the new data being appended to the files, it just overwrites the data originally in the file.

The data I am downloading is csv format text over a span of 7 days at a time. I run the program once a day to pull the new day's data and append it to the local file. Every time I run the program, the local file is a copy of the newly downloaded data with none of the old data. Since the data on the web site is only updated once a day, I have been testing by removing the last day's data in the local file and/or the first day's data in the local file. Any time I change the file and run the program, the file contains the downloaded data and nothing else.

I just tried something new to test why it wasn't working and think I have found the source of the error. When I ran on my local machine, the "filePath" variable was set to "". On the server and now on my local machine I have changed the "filePath" to @"C:\Solar Yard Data\" and on both machines it catches the file not found exception and creates a new file in the same directory which overwrites the original. Anyone have an idea as to why this happens?

The code is the section that download's each data set and appends any new data to the local file.

```
int i = 0;
string filePath = "C:/Solar Yard Data/";

string[] filenamesPower = new string[]
{
    "inverter121201321745_power",
    "inverter121201325108_power",
    "inverter121201326383_power",
    "inverter121201326218_power",
    "inverter121201323111_power",
    "inverter121201324916_power",
    "inverter121201326328_power",
    "inverter121201326031_power",
    "inverter121201325003_power",
    "inverter121201326714_power",
    "inverter121201326351_power",
    "inverter121201323205_power",
    "inverter121201325349_power",
    "inverter121201324856_power",
    "inverter121201325047_power",
    "inverter121201324954_power",
};

// download and save every module's power data
foreach (string url in modulesPower)
{

    // create web request and download data
    HttpWebRequest req_csv = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format(url, auth_token));
    req_csv.CookieContainer = cookie_container;
    HttpWebResponse res_csv = (HttpWebResponse)req_csv.GetResponse();

    // save the data to files
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res_csv.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string fileName = filenamesPower[i] + ".csv";

        // save the new data to file
        try
        {
            int startIndex = 0;          // start index for substring to append to file
            int searchResultIndex = 0;   // index returned when searching downloaded data for last entry of data on file
            string lastEntry;            // will hold the last entry in the current data
            //open existing file and find last entry
            using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                //get last line of existing data
                string fileContents = sr2.ReadToEnd();
                string nl = System.Environment.NewLine;  // newline string
                int nllen = nl.Length;                   // length of a newline
                if (fileContents.LastIndexOf(nl) == fileContents.Length - nllen)
                {
                    lastEntry = fileContents.Substring(0, fileContents.Length - nllen).Substring(fileContents.Substring(0, fileContents.Length - nllen).LastIndexOf(nl) + nllen);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastEntry = fileContents.Substring(fileContents.LastIndexOf(nl) + 2);
                }

                // search the new data for the last existing line
                searchResultIndex = response.LastIndexOf(lastEntry);
            }

            // if the downloaded data contains the last record on file, append the new data
            if (searchResultIndex != -1)
            {
                startIndex = searchResultIndex + lastEntry.Length;
                File.AppendAllText(filePath + fileName, response.Substring(startIndex+1));
            }
            // else append all the data
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The last entry of the existing data was not found\nin the downloaded data. Appending all data.");
                File.AppendAllText(filePath + fileName, response.Substring(109));  // the 109 index removes the file header from the new data
            }
        }
        // if there is no file for this module, create the first one
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // write data to file
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist, creating new data file.");
            File.WriteAllText(filePath + fileName, response);
            //Debug.WriteLine(response);
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Power file " + (i + 1) + " finished.");
    //Debug.WriteLine("File " + (i + 1) + " finished.");
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine("\nPower data finished!\n");
```

Comment: Q: Instead of creating "sr2" as a "StreamReader()" (and calling AppendText), why don't you open "StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (filename)", then append to it?  Just open two files: one to read from HTTP, the other to append to your .csv.  That's all you need - nothing else.

Comment: I have to append only the new data and the downloaded data will contain a lot of already saved data. I used "StreamReader sr2" in order to find the last recorded entry and then I search the new data for that entry and append everything after that to the local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of suggestions wich I think will probably resolve the issue
First change your filePath string

> string filePath = @"C:\Solar Yard Data\";

create a string with the full path

```
String fullFilePath = filePath + fileName;
```

then check to see if it exists and create it if it doesnt

```
if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath ))
     File.Create(fullFilePath );
```

put the full path to the file in your streamReader

```
using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(fullFilePath))
```

Comment: Yup, thanks. That was the problem I had. I kept changing paths around but had forgotten about the StreamReader object and it was throwing the FileNotFound exception causing the new file to overwrite the old.